# How to animate image by stacking them side by side in a row

Tags: java, swing, animation, animated-gif

I'm trying to build a swing application that shows images side by side one after another on click of a button. I'm using gif for animation since it's very easy but I could not find a way to custom gif in such a way that shows images stacked side by side with little time difference.

There's a way to do so in power point but I don't have it in my office's laptop.
The animated- gif I'm using currently shows the images on the same frame on top of each other but I need it to be side by side and one after another with a little time difference.

I'm new in UI programming, please suggest any solution.

Comment: It is not easy to extract images for a gif. An easier approach would be to create images that you load separately and then add the images to a JLabel and add the label to a panel.  You can use a Swing Timer for the animation. After you add each label to the panel you need to revalidate() the panel.

Comment: You can use [PowerPoint online](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/powerpoint).  Just click on the link on the page that says "Looking for PowerPoint on the web?".  You'll need to have a Microsoft account, though only a free one.

Comment: @camickr, Is there another way to use them as separate images into animation because I'm working on URCaps (a jar kind of file extension for UI of UR cobots) and there I can't access JPanel each time I'm hitting actionlistener of any type (A JButton in this case).

Comment: @BentheCoder , I'm using an online version of power point but to save any file there as a gif option is not available in online version.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry! I didn't realize that.  I use PowerPoint (the pay, desktop version) so thought the free version could do that too.